# Properties of sum appearing in Riemann's explicit formula

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Let $R(x)$ be Riemann's function defined as $R(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)\text{li}(x^{1/k})}{k}$ where $\mu$ is the Moebius function and li the logarithmic integral. Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. Let $\{\rho\}$ be the collection of non-trivial zeros on the critical line of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta$. Then it is known that $\pi(x)\sim R(x)-\sum_{\rho}R(x^\rho)$, or Riemann's explicit formula. It can be shown that the contribution of conjugate pairs of zeta zeros of the form $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\pm i\gamma$ that $R(x^{\rho})+R(x^{\bar{\rho}})$ grows as $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\frac{2\sin(\gamma\log(x))}{\gamma}$. Thus $\sum_{\rho}R(x^\rho)\sim\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\sum_{\gamma>0}\frac{2\sin(\gamma\log(x))}{\gamma}$. Now let $f(x)=\sum_{\gamma>0}\frac{2\sin(\gamma\log(x))}{\gamma}$ such that $\sum_{\rho}R(x^\rho)\sim\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}f(x)$. The term $\sqrt{x}/\log(x)$ is interpreted as the amplitude of the oscillatory sum, whereas $f(x)$ is suggested to be some term with no growth. A related quantity is $V(x)=\frac{R(x)-\pi(x)}{\sqrt{x}/\log(x)}$. My question is: what do we know about $V$ or $f$? I haven't been able to locate any information on these functions. In particular, I am curious if these are bounded, such as by unity, or if not, their asymptotic growth.

Comment: not sure what results you use as Littlewood theorem says that (even on RH) $\pi(x)-\mathrm{li} (x) =\Omega_{\pm}(\frac{\sqrt x \log \log \log x}{\log x})$ while if RH is false then $\pi(x)-\mathrm{li} (x)=\Omega_{\pm}(x^{\delta}), \delta>1/2$and since $R(x)=\mathrm{li} (x) +O(\sqrt x/ \log x)$ it is clear that $V$ cannot be bounded; similarly for $R(x^{\rho})$ even on RH that has to grow higher than $\sqrt x /\log x$ by the above

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Does this imply, under RH, that $V(x)=\Omega_{\pm}(\log\log\log x)$?

Comment: That's true unconditionally as Littlewood theorem is; since under RH we have $V=O(\log^2x)$ too its maximal growth order is in between somewhere then; of course if RH false then $V$ is $\Omega (x^{\delta})$ for some $\delta >0$; these are standard oscillating theorems

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: There are results about the average of $R$ and of $|R|$ known in literature (Ingham distribution prime numbers has references in the oscillation chapter at the end)

Comment: Thank you for the comments. One thing I find curious is that if you take the zeros $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\pm i\gamma$, the sum $f(x)=\sum_{\gamma>0}2\sin(\gamma\log(x))/\gamma$ converges (by Dirichlet's test for example). If you take $g(x)=\sum_{\gamma>0}4\sin^2(\gamma\log(x))/\gamma^2$, then it seems that $g(x)\sim \sum_{\Im\rho>0}\frac{2}{|\rho|^2} = 2 + \digamma - \log(4\pi)$ where $\digamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. This suggests that the sequence $(2\sin(\gamma\log(x))/\gamma: \gamma>0)$ is in $\ell^2$. This is different from $f(x)$, which does grow in $x$ as you point out.

Comment: Also I have located Ingham's book. It is excellent. Thank you for the reference.